# Extracting information from tpcdump

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpdump

i am using tpc dumnp to collect network statistics across two of my servers. I need help in order to decode logs.there are many pages explaining arguments we can pass but, where can i get details on how to use log dump. i started with basic command and i am trying wrap around messages I am getting.

set up :
node01 and node02 are two servers; node02 is copying a file to node01 over network following is output.

```
"tcpdump -i em2"
"14:36:40.102634 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [P.], seq 44496:44532, ack 147123477, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137079], length 36
14:36:40.102718 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147123477:147140853, ack 44496, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137079 ecr 718312460], length 17376
14:36:40.102728 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147140853, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137079], length 0
14:36:40.102867 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147140853:147158229, ack 44496, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137079 ecr 718312460], length 17376
14:36:40.102879 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147158229, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137079], length 0
14:36:40.103013 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147158229:147175605, ack 44496, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137079 ecr 718312460], length 17376
14:36:40.103024 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147175605, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137079], length 0
14:36:40.103160 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147175605:147185741, ack 44496, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137079 ecr 718312460], length 10136
14:36:40.103173 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147185741, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137079], length 0
14:36:40.103178 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147185741:147192981, ack 44532, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 7240
14:36:40.103185 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147192981, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0
14:36:40.103309 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147192981:147210357, ack 44532, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 17376
14:36:40.103321 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147210357, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0
14:36:40.103459 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147210357:147227733, ack 44532, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 17376
14:36:40.103471 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147227733, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0
14:36:40.103604 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147227733:147245109, ack 44532, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 17376
14:36:40.103614 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147245109, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0
14:36:40.103701 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [P.], seq 44532:44568, ack 147245109, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 36
14:36:40.103752 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147245109:147262485, ack 44532, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 17376
14:36:40.103760 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147262485, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0
14:36:40.103900 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147262485:147279861, ack 44532, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 17376
14:36:40.103911 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147279861, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0
14:36:40.104048 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147279861:147297237, ack 44532, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 17376
14:36:40.104061 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147297237, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0
14:36:40.104195 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147297237:147314613, ack 44532, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 17376
14:36:40.104210 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147314613, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0
14:36:40.104339 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147314613:147316061, ack 44532, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 1448
14:36:40.104352 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147316061:147331989, ack 44568, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 15928
14:36:40.104362 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147331989, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0
14:36:40.104490 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147331989:147349365, ack 44568, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 17376
14:36:40.104503 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147349365, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0
14:36:40.104638 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147349365:147366741, ack 44568, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 17376
14:36:40.104651 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147366741, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0
14:36:40.104785 IP node02.32769 > node01.ssh: Flags [.], seq 147366741:147384117, ack 44568, win 367, options [nop,nop,TS val 733137080 ecr 718312461], length 17376
14:36:40.104794 IP node01.ssh > node02.32769: Flags [.], ack 147384117, win 15023, options [nop,nop,TS val 718312461 ecr 733137080], length 0"
```

i see timestamp; followed by source > destination; but beyond that i dont understand other information 
what is Flags? seq? ack? win? options? length? in log dump above?

thanks

Comment: Use wireshark to help you decode all this. Also, read up on TCP. Here's the spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793

Comment: What are you trying to find out from this log?

Comment: @immibis i want to understand how packet/transaction latency changes with file size / interface bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

To understand those values you will need to read about TCP. You can begin here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol and then read TCP RFC.

- Flags: TCP flags (Sync, Push, Ack (dot), etc.)
- ACK, is the sequence number being acknowledged (next sequence number expected), SEQ the first sequence number being sent
- Win: the windows size published by the sender
- Length: for TCP payload
- Options: TCP options